# Systrace command line tool on windows doesn't work

Tags: android, systrace

I'm trying to start systrace.py on the windows 10 but got the following error

> File "C:\Users\smityukh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace....\devil\devil\utils\cmd_helper.py", line 97, in Popen
> preexec_fn=lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL))
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 664, in **init**
> raise ValueError("preexec_fn is not supported on Windows "
> ValueError: preexec_fn is not supported on Windows platforms

Please show me a way to start it.

UPDATE:

No way to use this script on Windows. Finally I have migrated on Mac and forget about any windows concerns related to android development.

And now in 2022 this script is not actual any more.